# How can I pass test-options with cabal new-test?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-new

In the old cabal, you could pass test options like `--color` and `--match=name` by doing `cabal test --test-option=--color --test-option=--match=name`. Can this be done with `cabal new-test`? I don't see a `--test-option` in the help output of `cabal new-test --help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, presumably because `new-test` runs all test suites, so it is unclear which test to pass it to.

But new versions of `cabal` tell you in the help for `new-test`:

> To pass command-line arguments to a test suite, see the new-run command.

so that is now the way to run a single test suite with options.

Comment: Although there is a [pull request](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/5455) that wants to fix this.